# Calculations from Text Files

Tags: c++

I have a text file that contains values as follows:

```
2013 05 27 15 52 02.049824 231.401 0.022 49.738   
2013 05 27 15 52 02.668822 229.814 0.019 49.738   
2013 05 27 15 52 03.283705 228.528 2.599 49.726   
2013 05 27 15 52 03.898469 230.140 2.576 49.751
```

Column1=date, Column2=Month, Column3=Day, Column4=Hour, Column5=Minute, Column6=Seconds, Column7=Voltage(Vrms), Column8=Current(Irms), Column9=Frequency(Hz).

I have to develop a program that will analyse these time-sampled voltage and current measurements over 24 hours and find the total energy used, mean and peak power consumption and Energy used over each hour of the 24 hour period.

How do I go about doing this?
I also have to include at least one numerical integration technique.
The file data contains over 50 thousand lines in the format mentioned above.

How do i input the data? This is what i tried.

```
using namespace std;

class DataTable{  
    public:   
        int year;   
        int month;  
        int day;   
        int hour;   
        int minute;   
        double seconds;   
        double voltage;   
        double current;   
        double frequency;   
};


int main(){  
    DataTable Data;

    ifstream DataFile("Data.txt");
    if (!DataFile)
        cout << "Unable to open" << endl;

        int year1, month1, day1, hour1, minute1;
        double seconds1, voltage1, current1, frequency1;
        while(DataFile >> year1 >> month1 >> day1 >> hour1 >> minute1 >> seconds1 >> voltage1 >> current1 >> frequency1)
        {
            Data.year = year1;
            Data.month = month1;
            Data.day = day1;
            Data.hour = hour1;
            Data.minute = minute1;
            Data.seconds = seconds1;
            Data.voltage = voltage1;
            Data.current = current1;
            Data.frequency = frequency1;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can start by learning a programming language.

Comment: I recommend learning a language such as Python ( even though you tagged this as C++), since it is a very friendly language for beginners, and can be picked up rather quickly

Answer (score 0):

> How do i input the data?

You want to have a `std::vector<DataTable>`, where you can store copies of your `Data` instance filled inside the while loop:

```
int main() {  

    ifstream DataFile("Data.txt");
    if (!DataFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int year1, month1, day1, hour1, minute1;
    double seconds1, voltage1, current1, frequency1;
    std::vector<DataTable> records;

    while(DataFile >> year1 >> month1 >> day1 >> hour1 >> minute1 >> seconds1 >>
                      voltage1 >> current1 >> frequency1) {
        DataTable Data;

        Data.year = year1;
        Data.month = month1;
        Data.day = day1;
        Data.hour = hour1;
        Data.minute = minute1;
        Data.seconds = seconds1;
        Data.voltage = voltage1;
        Data.current = current1;
        Data.frequency = frequency1;

        records.push_back(Data);
    }

    // Do something with records ...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to overload `operator>>` for the structure:

```
class DataTable{  
    public:   
        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, DataTable& dt);
        int year;   
        int month;  
        int day;   
        int hour;   
        int minute;   
        double seconds;   
        double voltage;   
        double current;   
        double frequency;   
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& inp, DataTable& dt)
{
    inp >> year;
    inp >> month;
    inp >> day;
    inp >> hour;
    inp >> minute;
    inp >> seconds;
    inp >> voltage;
    inp >> current;
    inp >> frequency;
    return inp;
};
```

Your input loop will look like:

```
std::vector<DataTable> data;
DataTable dt;
while (DataFile >> dt)
{
  data.push_back(dt);
}
```

One advantage to this paradigm is that the data structure can change without affecting the input loop.